# iOS Peripheral Not Receiving Write Requests after Power Toggle

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbperipheralmanager

I have an iOS app that is set up as a peripheral with a `CBPeripheralManager` and a service with several characteristics. I’m trying to achieve reconnection after the user opens Control Center and toggles Bluetooth off and on. It looks like my service resumes advertising correctly, but I am not ever getting any write request callbacks. I’m expecting `‑peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` to be called, but it never happens once Bluetooth is turned back on.

Is there anything special we need to do in this case? According to the `CBPeripheralManager` documentation, we only need to explicitly restart advertisement if the peripheral state goes below PoweredOff. I’m seeing it go to PoweredOff, then PoweredOn, and if I query it, `‑isAdvertising` returns `YES`, and adding the service crashes with an exception because the service is already added.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the write request to be received you need to first establish a connection to a peripheral, and then write to it.

Could it be that after the bluetooth is reset you are not re-establishing the connection?